# Can't find module '/opt/render/project/backend/app' on Render,

Tags: express, file, deployment, server, path

I have working live chat app on local machine and it is 100% working.
I am trying to upload it on Render.com.

But I have error that I can't fix while trying to deploy it.
Here is the error message:

[image]

So problem is that server.js can't find app.js file.

Here is my folder structure:
[image]

Current working directory in server.js file:

```
console.log("Current working directory:", process.cwd());
console.log(
  "File path for app module:",
  path.join(__dirname, "../backend/app")
);

Current working directory: F:\REACT-PROJECT-FOLDER\chat app\backend
File path for app module: F:\REACT-PROJECT-FOLDER\chat app\backend\app
```

In server.js file I am trying to import it like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const app = require(path.join(__dirname, "../backend/app"));
```

I tried also to upload it to vercel, but it does not work.

Comment: Why not `const app = require('./app')`?